# ¿Por qué se cumple el primer condicional con el if pero con el segundo if no se cumple?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un inconveniente acá donde el usuario introduce la edad y la valida para saber si es o no apto para entrar al local, pero luego intento validar el horario para saber si la entrada es gratis o no entre las 2 y las 7 por ejemplo, y no encuentro definir esa parte de la lógica. ¿Quizás este utilizando el ciclo inadecuadamente?

```js
let free =false;

const validarCliente = (horario)=>{
    edad= prompt('cual es tu edad?');
    if (edad> 18){
        if (horario >= 2 && horario < 7 && free == false) {
            alert ('podes pasar gratis');
            free = true;
        } else {
            alert ('podes pasar pero tenes que pagar la entrada');
        }

    } else {
        alert ('sos menor de edad , no podes pasar');
    }

}

validarCliente(23);
validarCliente(24);
validarCliente(0.2);
validarCliente(0.6);
validarCliente(1);
validarCliente(2);
validarCliente(2.4);
validarCliente(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función no recibe parámetros, al llamarla te pedirá la edad y si es mayor a 18 te pregunta el horario, en caso de cumplir ambas condiciones te dirá que puedes ingresar gratis en caso contrario de la primera condición directamente no puedes ingresar por ser menor de edad.

Si ese es todo tu código no veo necesidad de la variable free.

```
const validarCliente = ()=> {
    edad = prompt('cual es tu edad?')
    let free=false
    if(edad>=18){
    horario = prompt('dime el horario')
        if(horario>2 && horario<7){
            alert ('Puedes pasar gratis')
        }else{
            alert('Puedes pasar pero tienes que pagar')
        }
    }else{
        alert('Eres menor de edad, no puedes pasar')
    }}

validarCliente()
```

Comment: probé tu código @kevinrueda e igual no funcionó. También me di cuenta que en la edad de 18 hay que poner >= pues sino al introducir 18 te lo toma como que el usuario es menor de edad también. Pero lo cierto es que todavía no encuentro como hacer que funcione.

Comment: Ese es mi código completo bro...

Comment: Ahora veo que pasan 2 cosas: una es que una vez ingresada la edad, sea menor de 18 o igual o mayor a 18, el ciclo no finaliza sino que se queda en un bucle infinito preguntando la edad.  Traté de hacerlo mediante break, pero no sirvió. La otra cosa que observo es que me doy cuenta que horario lo paso por parametro de la función validar cliente, pero nunca pregunto por prompt lo del horario... no se si me explico: esta allí la comparación del horario en el segundo if pero eso nunca se utiliza pues nunca se pregunta al respecto. ¿Puedes ayudarme a definir mejor esas 2 cosas?

Comment: @OtroMasComoTu por favor revisa la corrección del código, ya cumple con lo que pides, te ahorre pedir como parámetro el horario que viene ser irrelevante si el cliente es menor de edad por eso solo lo pide si cumple la condición de mayor de edad